# Count values in a table (in R)

Tags: r

I have a table. I would like to count how many of the values start with 11_ and at the same time equal to 1.

```
11_AAACCCAAGAGCTGCA 11_AAACCCACAAAGACGC 11_AAACCCAGTCACTTAG 11_AAACGAACAAAGGCTG 
        6                      3                      1                      1 
11_AAACGAATCCACACAA 13_AAACGCTCACATGAAA 13_AAACGCTCAGCGGTCT 11_AAACGCTCATGGAAGC 
        7                      1                      3                      1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a named vector?

You can combine the two conditions to filter name and value.

```
x <- c('11_AAACCCAAGAGCTGCA' = 6, 
       '11_AAACCCACAAAGACGC' = 3, 
       '11_AAACCCAGTCACTTAG' = 1, 
       '11_AAACGAACAAAGGCT' = 1, 
       '11_AAACGAATCCACACAA' = 7, 
       '13_AAACGCTCACATGAAA' = 1, 
       '13_AAACGCTCAGCGGTCT' = 3, 
       '11_AAACGCTCATGGAAGC' = 1)

x[startsWith(names(x), '11_') & x == 1]

#11_AAACCCAGTCACTTAG  11_AAACGAACAAAGGCT 11_AAACGCTCATGGAAGC 
#                  1                   1                   1 

#To count

sum(startsWith(names(x), '11_') & x == 1)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.. since I don't have a vector it is a table...

Comment: @giegie Please provide data in a reproducible format so that we can test our answers.

Comment: @giegie By table do you mean a dataframe? What is `11_AAACCCAAGAGCTGCA` ? Is it a rowname? If so, the logic is still the same use `rownames` instead of `names` and use `df$column_name` instead of `x`. It would be helpful if you share sample of your actual data for us to understand the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grepl`

```
sum(grepl("^11_", names(x)) & x == 1)
```